# Proving uniform continuity via Lagrange's theorem (mean value theorem)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on an interval $I$. Prove:
$$f \prime \, \text{is bounded on $I$} \Rightarrow f \, \text{is uniformly continuous on I}$$

I'm supposed to solve this using Lagrange's theorem.

My attempt:

Recall the definition of uniform continuity:
$$\forall \varepsilon>0 \exists \delta>0 \forall x,y \in I \colon(|x-y|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon)$$
Now suppose $f \prime$ is bounded on $I$. Then:
$$\exists x_1 \in I \colon \forall x_2 \in I \colon |f \prime(x_1)| \geq |f \prime (x_2)|$$
Let $x,y \in I$ be arbitrary. By Lagrange's theorem:
$$\exists \xi \in (x,y):|f(x)-f(y)|=|f \prime(\xi)||x-y| \leq |f \prime(x_1)||x-y|< \varepsilon$$
So let's recap:
$$|x-y|< \frac{\varepsilon}{|f \prime (x_1)|} \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|< \varepsilon$$
So we have found $\delta$ and we use $\delta:= \frac{\varepsilon}{|f \prime (x_1)|}$

This concludes the proof. Is this valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your proof is entirely correct (except you write "uniform convergence" where you mean "uniform continuity").  Well, to be extremely picky I suppose you should explain what happens when $f'(x_1) = 0$, since then you can't perform the division, but that is a trivial case.

Note that you are actually showing that $f$ is [Lipschitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity): we say $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is **Lipschitz** if there is a constant $C$ such that for all $x_1,x_2 \in I$, $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)| \leq C|x_1-x_2|$.

It is helpful to think in terms of the stronger conclusion, because Lipschitz functions have many other nice properties.  (For instance, any Lipschitz function is [absolutely continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolutely_continuous) and thus differentiable almost everywhere.  These are more advanced concepts and you may not have encountered them yet, but if you take a graduate level course on real analysis, you certainly will.)